# What's the best way to find out the max number of records a table contains over a day's time?

Tags: mysql, laravel

I'm currently working with a LAMP stack that uses Laravel framework and we use a `sessions` table within MySQL to manage user sessions. If a user's session expires then their record is removed from that table (120 minutes of no activity / logging out), and when a user newly logs in to the app a new record is added. Already logged in users that perform an action within the app have their pre-existing `sessions` record updated with a timestamp of when their most recent action occurred.

That in mind, what I'm wanting to find out is the daily upper bound of how many many users are concurrently logged into the app. What I currently have in mind is adding a trigger to that table that writes to another, newly created table, that contains one record per day and simply adds/subtracts from a 'concurrent_users_logged_in' field each time a user logs in/out, but I'm wondering if there's a more clever/lightweight/mainstream way of doing this?

Comment: Sounds like a job for `COUNT(*), DATE(on_date) AS by_date GROUP BY by_date`

Comment: Records are removed if a session expires. I.e., it's like a 'real-time' table. Data doesn't stay in the table for any longer that a user's session is active.

Comment: If you keep deleting them you can't report on them. You'll need to keep track somewhere else. Maybe run a job periodically and insert `COUNT(*) FROM x` into that table? As a note, `COUNT(*)` can **melt down your database and wreck your application** on tables of non-trivial size with heavy write activity.

Comment: Lazy way: Add a trigger. Easy way: [Event Scheduler](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/events-overview.html). Neither of these will perform efficiently, but they might be adequate.

Comment: FWIW, I can also say that the max number of active user sessions I've seen so far is under 100.

Comment: Shouldn't be a problem then. Try making a statistics table you can `INSERT INTO ... SELECT COUNT(*) FROM y` on a periodic basis. You could also use `REPLACE INTO` or `INSERT INTO ... ON DUPLICATE KEY` if you want to handle collisions, as in multiple samples per day, to get the high/low/avg etc.

Comment: This is also where external tools like [Grafana](https://grafana.com) can come into play.

Comment: If you want to analyse data, don't delete data. Don't update session time stamps. Instead, separately store a timestamp for each activity. (Although for this specific example, it's sufficient to update the session - and deleting sessions is irrelevant and unnecessary)